Evenly distribute shifts among persons who belongs to multiple rooms
Please, consider this sample input data:



Name
I
II
III




F1
X




F2

X



F3
X

X


F4
X
X
X



where, F1..4 are four persons and I-III are three rooms.
The X means that person belongs to the room.
A constant defines the numbers of weekends each room has to be cleaned, let's say:
N = 10

A person can only clean the room(s) to which he belongs.
The goal is to try to have the same number of shifts as much as possible, considering who belongs to several rooms.
The desired output is then a list of people for each room and the expected numbers of shifts.
For the given example above, a possible solution could be:



Room
People
Shifts




I
F1
7



F3
3


II
F2
7



F4
3


III
F3
5



F4
5



in this way:

F1 has 7 shifts
F2 has 7 shifts
F3 has 8 shifts
F4 has 8 shifts

among all the possible solutions it should prefer the one(s) with the minimum difference in shifts (in this example it is 1).
Here I decided to assign 0 shifts for F4 in room I, but since the goal is to make equal numbers of shifts for all people, they can be distruted in a different manner if useful.
I'm going to find an algorithm so I can write a software to outputs the results.
Because this is a real-case scenario, please feel free to ask any detail I may forgot to add!
Can you help me to find a suitable algorithm to solve the problem?

@greybeard question edited, thanks
